# Audit VueJs / Nuxt components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there a tool that can run through a Nuxt project to determine a list of components and where they're referenced. Looking to refactor an existing codebase and trying to determine dependencies and most productive path to rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome extension **Vue.js devtools** which shows the component hierarchy and dependencies you can use it to understand the structure and flow pretty much everything going in your vue app.

Comment: Thank you. That displays what's loaded on the specific page, I was hoping to get something that walks through the entire application (all pages) to generate the information.